# Where is Map.Entry toString() method implementation defined, given that Map.entry is an interface?

Tags: collections, hashmap

Here we can see Map.Entry toString() method in action.
Where is that defined since Map.Entry is an interface.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;



class Dog
{
    public int i;
    public int hashCode()
        {
            return i%3;
        }
    Dog(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return i +  "" ;
    }

}
class ShellClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        HashMap m = new HashMap(5,(float)0.8);
        for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            m.put((new Dog(i)),"dog");
        }

        System.out.println(m); // line1
        Set entrySet = m.entrySet();
        System.out.println(entrySet); // line2
        Iterator itr = entrySet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry element = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
            System.out.println(element); // line3
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following output:

```
{3=dog, 1=dog, 4=dog, 2=dog} //output by line 1
[3=dog, 1=dog, 4=dog, 2=dog] //output by line 2 Map.Entry toString in action
3=dog // output by line 3 (Map.Entry toString in action)
1=dog // output by line 3 (Map.Entry toString in action)
4=dog // output by line 3 (Map.Entry toString in action)
2=dog // output by line 3 (Map.Entry toString in action)
```

Can you please tell where is Map.Entry toString() method implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my reference implementation of the java standard library, there is a static inner class within `HashMap` that implments the `Map.Entry` interface.

That inner class is, for better or for worse, "also" named `Entry`.

You can see it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#691). Its [`toString` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#741) looks like this:

```
     public final String toString() {
         return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer pnkfelix